# How to override vim plugin ctrl-p bindinds

Tags: vim

I was using a vim config : https://github.com/astrails/dotvim

In this config I was able to bind ctrl+p to nerdtree and I got used to it. Now I'm trying to build my own vim config and even though I bind nerdtree to ctrl-p in my vim config using `nmap <leader>p :NERDTreeFind<CR>`, it's being overridden by the plugin Ctrl-P.

How can I get vim to use my binding and not the ctrlp one?

I know it's possible because somewhere in the package I was using it was done, but I can't figure out where. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let g:ctrlp_map = '<c-p>'`

Change as needed (this is the default). You can see all the configuration variables by typing `:help ctrlp<CR>`.